# Resource recommendation on quantum simulations

Tags: resource-request, simulation, hamiltonian-simulation, vqe, qaoa

I would like to know more about quantum simulations, so as to start on a few standard physical models (maybe particle in a box, harmonic oscillator, etc.) and then build up on more complex things. But I find that the literature on this subject seems a bit scattered all over the place. I only know some guide lines, I know that I have to look into trotterization, VQE and (maybe?) QAOA. But is there a "place" or book that compiles all of it?

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat late, but the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_simulation) page has aggregated some of the main techniques for quantum Hamiltonian simulation.

If you're looking for a bit more of a walkthrough (over scientific papers), Microsoft provides a [good overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/user-guide/libraries/chemistry/concepts/algorithms) of both Trotteriation / Qubitization. IBM also talks about [VQEs](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/vqe-molecules.html).